# Pulling Web Data with R

Tags: r, xml, web-scraping, rcurl, httr

I am wondering if it is possible to pull web data with R. Specifically, would it be possible to log into a web page, go to a specific web page that stores Crystal Reports. Then, enter in your parameters--there are about 6 fields you can enter select dates and other criteria. The web site is an internal website so I can't share the exact website with you. Something similar I found is at the link below:

[[Scrape password-protected website in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723606/scrape-password-protected-website-in-r][1])

However, instead of going to a webpage after a login page, and pulling a data file I would want to go to a web page and enter in the 6 parameters and click submit for the report to generate.

I'm looking to automate this process to save time since I have to do this with about 5 different websites weekly. I know I didn't provide enough info for testing, but in general, would this be possible? I'll try to find a public website to help explain this better.

Thanks

Comment: I'd suggest RSelenium for this.

Comment: Have a look at the question you are referencing to. There even is a RSelenium example as hrbmstr suggests. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723606/scrape-password-protected-website-in-r#answer-24724774