# Web scraping with R using rvest for financial website

Tags: r, web-scraping, finance, rvest

I am trying to scrape data table from following website using R, but it is not returning any value. I am using `SelectorGadget` to get the nodes detail.

```
library(rvest)
url = "http://www.bursamalaysia.com/market/derivatives/prices/"

text <- read_html(url) %>% 
html_nodes("td") %>% 
html_text()

output:

text
character(0)
```

I would appreciate any kind of help. Thank you!

Comment: Where is the code that uses SelectorGadget?

Comment: are you sure there are any "td" nodes?

Comment: It looks like the page is dynamiclly created with javascript.  There is some information stored here: http://www.bursamalaysia.com/searchbox_data.json?_=1495066355942 .  Most likely not the information you are looking for

Comment: @42 In `rvest` tutorial it's mention that CSS selectors are used to select elements based on properties. In `html_nodes("td")` , "td", I am getting using SelectorGadget.

Comment: @Phi, "td" I am getting using SelectorGadget. I might be wrong here. Please guide.

Comment: @Dave2e, That means, it's not easy to pull data from this website. Excuse me for dumb question.

Comment: Yes, it is not straight forward to pull from this website.  Take a look at the RSelenium package.  That might help

Comment: try this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723606/scrape-password-protected-website-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1