# Using Rvest to log into Financial Times' Website

Tags: r, web-scraping, rvest, httr

I am using the following R codes to log into the FT website, which requires filling in two forms: the first one for email and the second for password.

```
library("rvest")
library(httr)
uastring="Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:53.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/53.0"
session1 <- html_session("https://accounts.ft.com/login")
uem="my@email"
pwd="mypassword"
form1 <- html_form(session1)[[1]]
form1 <- set_values(form1, email=uem)
session2 <- submit_form(session1, form1)
form2<- html_form(session2)[[1]]
form2 <- set_values(form2, email=uem,password=pwd,rememberMe="true")
session3 <- submit_form(session2, form2)
capture.output(cat(content(session3$response,as='text')),file="s3html.html")
```

The last line is to get the webpage after submitting my credentials. When I opened the resulting html document in Firefox, I saw that the log-in was not succesful with an error code: LAE002 (pls see the attached picture). Can anyone shed some light on this? Many thanks.

[image: ft log in]

Comment: try looking into https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723606/scrape-password-protected-website-in-r?noredirect=1&lq=1