# Scraping a website protected by a password in R

Tags: r, web-scraping

I've looked for information regarding this problem (such as found here: [Scrape password-protected website in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723606/scrape-password-protected-website-in-r) and threads linked to it) but I can't solve the quirks for my particular website.

I'd like to to use this website http://www.footballdatabase.eu/ which is password protected. Once logged in I would navigate to a webpage to start scraping. I've set up the code as follows:

```
url <- "http://www.footballdatabase.eu"
login <- list(login = "username", password = "password")

response <- POST(url = url, body = login)
```

After I would then set navigate to a webpage by entering a new link:

```
link <- "http://www.footballdatabase.eu/football.match.cagliari.ac-milan.1141156.en.html"
doc <- htmlParse(link, encoding = "UTF-8")
table <- readHTMLTable(doc)
```

and then I would take the information from the table.

I would like it setup so that in theory I could either loop through multiple webpages after logging in once, or logging in each team (if that's more convenient). Currently I get the following output from response:

Response [http://www.footballdatabase.eu/]
  Date: 2017-05-31 01:03
  Status: 200
  Content-Type: text/html
  Size: 2.17 kB
You have exceeded your amount of pages visited during the day. Please sign in with your login or register.

Thank you for any help!

Comment: You might want to try out what's done in [this example](https://github.com/hadley/rvest/blob/master/demo/united.R). I think you'll want to open the session, login, then navigate around within the same session.

Comment: That error message could indicate your login is not working and the site things you are just a robot.

Comment: @austensen I've had look at this but unfortunately I don't think the page uses a log-in form. I've not been able to work out how to select the button.

Comment: @MarkStewart It's definitely not working currently, I'm just at a loss how to click the button to log in since the page doesn't appear to use a form. It's something to do with this "connectu" variable in the HTML