# Use R Scipt to Login to Web site and perform some kind of action

Tags: r

How can I use R to login to a web site and perform some action?  I think the code below is very close, but something seems to be off here.

```
library(httr)
library(XML)

handle <- handle("http://subscribers.footballguys.com") 
path   <- "amember/login.php"

# fields found in the login form.
login <- list(
  amember_login = "username"
 ,amember_pass  = "password"
 ,amember_redirect_url = 
   "https://www.google.com/accounts/Login"
)
```

## THEN

```
response <- POST(handle = handle, path = path, body = login)
```

Any insight into this would be most appreciated.

Comment: I'm assuming you have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24723606/scrape-password-protected-website-in-r?rq=1) which seems to be solving the same problem?

Comment: Yeah.  That works.  I think the site was down earlier today when I tried to run this.  I couldn't even access it by copying/pasting the URL into my browser.  Anyway, it seems to be working now.  Thanks.